# Problem with FindGeneratingFunction

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, sequence

I have a lengthy function of a real parameter $n$ that generates values $val$ for each $n$ {$n$, $val$}:

```
 arr = {{1,26}, {2,26}, {3,26}, {4,50}, {5,106}, {6,266}, {7,586}, {8,1170}, {9,2186}, {10,4106}, {11,7946}, {12,15890}, {13,32266}, {14,65546}, {15,132106}, {16,264210}, {17,526346}, {18,1048586}, {19,2093066}, {20,4186130}}
```

I am using `FindGeneratingFunction` to find an expression that generates this array of values for each n.

```
FindGeneratingFunction[arr, n]
```

This generates the result

$$2 \left(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{1+i x}+\frac{2}{1-2 x}+\frac{2}{1-(1-i) x}+\frac{1}{1-i x}+\frac{2}{1-(1+i) x}+\frac{6}{1-x}\right).$$

However, this does not reproduce the array of values. Why is `FindGeneratingFunction` returning an incorrect expression and how can I determine an expression given the array above?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this does not reproduce the array of values."? Expanding it in power series gives $30 + 26x + 26x^2 + 26x^3 + 50x^4 + 106x^5 + ...$ so what am  I missing?

Comment: Are you possibly looking for `FindSequenceFunction` rather than `FindGeneratingFunction`?

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @Somos : a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) is a rather specific mathematical beast with rather specific applications.

Comment: @JimB @Somos, I did indeed intend to use `FindSequenceFunction`. Will delete the question, but before I do, what exactly then does `FindGeneratingFunction ` do?

Comment: It finds a function gives you the value of your given sequence as a function of an integer value $n$ (and will extrapolate to values of $n$ that you haven't listed assuming that is appropriate to assume).  But if your values of $n$ are not all positive integers, then you're really wanting to perform a regression.